# Best way to assign database value to a String type variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, if-statement, null

If I have a `DataRow` value and I want to assign it to a `String` variable, is the following an effective way to do this and assign an empty string if the `DataRow` value is `Null`?

```
Dim string1 As String = If(myDataRow("column1"), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work since `myDataRow("column1")` is not `Nothing` but `DBNull.Value`.

I would use the strongly typed `Field` extension method which also supports nullable types;

```
Dim string1 = If(myDataRow.Field(Of String)("column1"), "")
```

If you want to use the old way:

```
Dim string1 = If(myDataRow.IsNull("column1"), "", DirectCast(myDataRow("column1"), String))
```

Comment: Is `DataRow.Field` in VS2010?

Comment: Is the `DirectCast` necessary?  I thought `DataRow` values are typed according to their database source type?

Comment: @CJ7: Yes, it is available in .NET 4. Maybe you have upgraded this project. Then you need to add the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` to the project's references. The `DirectCast` is necessary since `myDataRow("column1")` is of type `Object`. If it's not necessary you should set  `OPTION STRICT` to `on` immediately ;-)

Comment: Is `myDataRow("column1").IsNull` preferred to `IsDBNull(myDataRow("column1")`   ?

Comment: @CJ7: I would prefer `DataRow.IsNull` instead of "magic" helper functions which might work or not. However, it is not `myDataRow("column1").IsNull` but `myDataRow.IsNull("column1")`. I prefer to know what happens. That's why i also prefer `int.Parse` over  `Convert.ToInt32`. Also, the `Convert` methods often have to cast to other types which is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a function like this:

```
Shared Function DBNull2Space(ByVal objValue As Object) As Object

    If IsDBNull(objValue) Then
        DBNull2Space = Space(0)
    Else
        DBNull2Space = objValue
    End If

End Function
```

This is the call to the function:

```
Dim strTest as String = DBNull2Space(myDataRow("column1"))
```

Comment: This function is only useful for String types so you might as well return a `String` rather than an `Object`. Your call to the function will fail with Option Strict On as it stands, so this is another reason to change it

Comment: Thanks! Never notice that since I created this function in 2004 and put it in my library! :) I think that I declare it like this because I simply reversed a Space2DBNull function which must return an Object (DBNull.Value or objValue).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Dim string1 As String = If(IsDBNull(myDataRow.Item("column1")), "",myDataRow.Item("column1"))
```

Comment: You should use the IF Operator instead of the IIF Function, as it provides short-circuiting and type safety

Comment: Is `IsDBNull(myDataRow("column1")` preferred to `myDataRow("column1").IsNull` ?

Comment: @CJ7 .. I think so, and the different is that IsDBNull is function and IsNull is methode .. But anyway, is this help you ?